# Is there a way to not show some fields of a content type on the add form?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, users

I have a content type "Print" with several fields. Some fields need to be filled out by users and thus, should be hidden from the anonymous users who create content of type "Print." Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module sounds exactly like what you're after.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> **Features**
>
> Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes. Role-based
>   field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what
>   access the user has. Author-level permissions allow viewing and
>   editing of fields based on who the entity owner is. Permissions for
>   each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can
>   enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature
>   is needed. Field permissions overview

Simply don't give anonymous users permission to add/edit these fields.

Comment: @Mike No problem - don't forget to accept if it works ;-)